# javascript to show hide Ul>li on anchor tag click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open a `ul` which will have dynamic `li` when I click on a anchor tag.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="shop-category"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>SHOP ALL CATEGORIES</span></a>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ tree_category.get_absolute_url }}">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>
            <span class="title">{{tree_category}}</span>  
</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I have done so far is :

```
<script>
    $(".shop-category").filter(function(){
        return ( $(this).siblings('ul').length > 0 );
        }).on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // hide sibling ul element (if it exists)
        $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
    });
</script>
```

But No luck.

Comment: What do you mean with no luck? when i run the code it hides and shows the ul

Comment: Do you want to know how to generate the dynamic <li>(s)? What is the issue be more specific.

Comment: No it doesn't work for me. not on firefox and not on chrome not on any browser @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: yes i know that. actual i haven't posted that code but the whole list of LI is comming  @ThatAwesomeCoder

Comment: Are you running your code in document.ready handler? Any error in console?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't forgotten to include the **jQuery library** for this to work? If so then I highly recommend you start opening the browser console to check for errors.

Comment: I check his code on snippet and its works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I think you are missing something inside script tag. Please replace below codes. Hope your issue will be solved. Have a good luck. here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".shop-category").filter(function(){
  return ( $(this).siblings('ul').length > 0 );
  }).on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // hide sibling ul element (if it exists)
  $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
});
});
```